# How to use RunNotifier or RunListener using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test, spring-junit

I want to get notified when a test fails. Ideally, I want to know if the test is passed or failed in my @After annotated method. I understand that their is a RunListener which can be used for this purpose but it works only if we run the test with JunitCore. Is there a way to get notified if a test case fails or something similar to RunListener which can be used with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Spring TestContext Framework provides a `TestExecutionListener` SPI that can be used to achieve this.

Basically, if you implement `TestExecutionListener` (or better yet extend `AbstractTestExecutionListener`), you can implement the `afterTestMethod(TestContext)` method. From the `TestContext` that is passed in you can access the exception that was thrown (if there is one).

Here's the Javadoc for `org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getTestException()`:

> Get the exception that was thrown during execution of the test method.
>
> Note: this is a mutable property.
>
> Returns: the exception that was thrown, or null if no exception was
>   thrown

FYI: you can register your customer listener via the `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation.

Regards,

Sam

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam. I am using testexecutionlistener now.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is JUnits builtin `TestWatcher` Rule.

The rule allows you to opt into what things you want to be notified for. Here is a compacted example from [JUnit Github Docs](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules#testwatchmantestwatcher-rules)

```
@Test 
public class WatcherTest {

  @Rule
  public final TestRule watcher = new TestWatcher() {

    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description) {}

    // More overrides exists for starting, finished, succeeded etc
  };

  @Test
  public void test() {}
}
```